# Combinatoric proof of $\binom{j-1}{m-1}=\sum_{k=m}^j(-1)^{k-m}\binom{j}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, alternative-proof

I want the combinatoric proof of the following identity:

\begin{align*}
{\binom{j-1}{m-1}=\sum_{k=m}^j(-1)^{k-m}\binom{j}{k}}
\end{align*}

i.e. the left hand side choose what $(m-1)$ out of what $(j-1)$, I need a concrete example.

**Note after solved this:** Just use the Pascal Rule, since the combinatorics proof can't explain why the result is always positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say we have $j$ boys and a coach want to form a group of at least $m$ members.

The coach claim that he can form as many groups with even number of boys as groups with odd number of boys. His reasoning: for any even group, he can make the oldest boy of these $j$ join or leave the group to make it an odd group and vice versa.

The assistant coach disagree. His reasoning: there are groups with exactly $m$ boys including the oldest. The coach cannot make the oldest boy leave the group because then the group will have less than $m$ members. There are $\binom{j-1}{m-1}$ groups like this.

$$
\rule{6cm}{0.4pt}
$$

Here is an alternative for non combinatorial proof.

We use identity $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n-1}{i-1}+\binom{n-1}{i}$

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^{j}{\left(-1\right)^{k—m}\binom{j}{k}}&=\binom{j}{m}+\binom{j}{m+2}+...-\binom{j}{m+1}-\binom{j}{m+3}-...\\
&=\binom{j-1}{m-1}+\binom{j-1}{m}+\binom{j-1}{m+1}+\binom{j}{m+2}+...-\binom{j-1}{m}-\binom{j-1}{m+1}-\binom{j-1}{m+2}-\binom{j-1}{m+3}-...\\
&=\binom{j-1}{m-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @FtyRain try to sub $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n-1}{i}+\binom{n-1}{i-1}$

Comment: I decomposed each term by the Pascal Rule you provided, and what left is $\binom{j-1}{m-1}\pm\binom{j-1}{j}=\binom{j-1}{m-1}$. But I think this cannot be represented in the coach analogy.

Comment: @FtyRain hi there, I edited the answer to include alternative proof. Notice that the terms cancel each other, leaving $\binom{j-1}{m-1}$